# Scrapy css selector: get text of all inner tags

Tags: html, css, scrapy

I have a tag and I want to get all the text inside available. I am doing this:

```
response.css('mytag::text')
```

But it is only getting the text of the current tag, I also want to get the text from all the inner tags.

I know I could do something like:

```
response.xpath('//mytag//text()')
```

But I would like to do it with `css` selectors. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
response.css('mytag *::text')
```

The `*` will visit all the inner tags of `mytag` and `::text` will get the text of each of them

Answer (score 17):

Get text of only selected node.

```
response.css('mytag::text')
```

Get text of selected node and its child nodes.

```
response.css('mytag ::text')
```

See the difference between these two versions. The only difference is the space. If there is no space then only text/attributes of current nodes are returned. If there is space then it selects text/attributes of self and child nodes

```
response.css('h1 a::attr(href)') # only current node attribute

response.css('h1 ::attr(href)') # current node and all child nodes attribute.
```

Comment: can you please show where did you get this? It's not working for me

Comment: I use them mostly in scrapy and they work without any issue.

Comment: Cristal clear. Love 'em. Thanks for saving my day.