# Get all text including html in a single node scrapy xpath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="blah"]//text()')
```

Suppose my html is

```
<p id="blah">This is a simple text <a href="#">foo</a> and this is after tag. </p>
```

What is happening i get a list of text even though its one `<p>` tag. Such as

```
[u'This is a simple text', u' and this is after tag.']
```

My actual html content is huge and I have to do `join` in order to achieve this. Also i lose `foo` while `join`. Is there any specific `xpath` `scrapy` mechanism of doing this ?

I want to get result 
**This is a simple text foo and this is after tag.**

Please notice the `foo` here too.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985060/scrapy-css-selector-get-text-of-all-inner-tags

Comment: also applicable to xpath ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all text nodes as single string as below:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="blah"]')[0].text_content()
```

Output:

```
'This is a simple text foo and this is after tag. '
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's xpath 2 you can use the string-join function

```
response.xpath('string-join(//*[@id="blah"]//text())')
```