# Python - Why <br> breaks XPath text() in Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

When I try to scrap post from forum shown below, using Scrapy and Xpath:

`item['post'] = response.xpath('.//div[@class="post-content"]//p/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')`

Source code:

```
<div class="post-content" data-post-id="1466409">
                    <p>Hello,<br />
I would like to create an application</p>
```

however I get only `"Hello,"`.

Any ideas on how we can solve it to get:

`Hello,\nI would like to create an application`?`

Comment: please add your code to post

Comment: @Alexey I forgot about it. I updated post.

Comment: Sounds like a case of a method doing exactly as the name advertises ... `extract_first`. Go with `extract()`, and join the results together using a line break character if necessary ...?

Comment: Encounter similar problem when I try css selector with a tag <wbr> in tag <h1>. Unfortunately, response.css('h1::text').extract() won't work. Fix the problem with response.css('h1 ::text'). Here's more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985060/scrapy-css-selector-get-text-of-all-inner-tags

Answer (score 1):

you can use this  `:/p[descendant-or-self::text()]`

Comment: It's indeed works, can you please add more details, how it's working? I mean this: `response.xpath('//div[@class="post-content"]/p[descendant-or-self::text()]').extract()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrapy shell to test small parts of html:

Create `test.html`:

```
<div class="post-content" data-post-id="1466409">
                    <p>Hello,<br />
I would like to create an application</p></div>
```

Then run `scrapy shell ./test.html`

```
>> ' '.join(response.xpath('//div[@class="post-content"]//p/text()').extract())
'Hello, \nI would like to create an application'
```

Or, if you want only first post, update `test.html`:

```
<div class="post-content" data-post-id="1466409">
                    <p>Hello,<br />
I would like to create an application</p></div>

<div class="post-content" data-post-id="1466410">
                    <p>Hello,<br />
I would like to create an application1</p></div>
```

run scrapy shell again `scrapy shell ./test.html`:

```
>>> ' '.join(response.xpath('//div[@data-post-id="1466409"]//p/text()').extract())
```

But, I guess, you don't know each post's `data-post-id`, so, in this case you can do something like this to get the first post:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> first_post=response.xpath('//div[@class="post-content"]').extract_first()
>>> alist=BeautifulSoup(first_post).findAll('p')
>>> ''.join([p.get_text() for p in alist])
'Hello,\nI would like to create an application'
```

Or, to iterate over all posts:

```
>>> all_posts=response.xpath('//div[@class="post-content"]').extract()
>>> for post in all_posts:
...     alist=BeautifulSoup(post).findAll('p')
...     ''.join([p.get_text() for p in alist])
... 
'Hello,\nI would like to create an application'
'Hello,\nI would like to create an application1'
```

Comment: But I have multiple posts and `extract()` doesn't extract only one post but multiple.

Comment: do you need only all `p` from first post?

Comment: Yes, but my program extract all forum posts. So I iterate over all topics and extract all posts. So I need to extract all data from post. I need only text and \n from every post.

Comment: This is my source code https://pastebin.com/nVJvqSjS Maybe it will be clearer what I want to achieve.

Comment: What does json have to do with it? Just create sample `test.html` as I did and test it via `scrapy shell`

Answer (score 0):

Your `p` has three elements:

- A text element containing "Hello,"
- A `br` element
- A text element containing "I would like to create an application"

Your selector gets all (both of) the text elements in the `p`. Then, with `extract_first()`, you asked for the first of them. Hence, it should not be a surprise that the result contains "Hello,".

If you want to obtain *all* the content of `p`, and replace the `br` element with a newline, you will have to do that yourself.

Comment: But how can I extract the whole post? I have multiple posts so using `extract()` instead of `extract_first()` will extract multiple posts. My code works properly but there is a problem in situation as I have described in question.